# Black VNC for a new user

Tags: linux, vnc

I setup a user from ssh, but when I tried to log in with VNC client, it gave me a black screen. VNC works well for other users. I tried to log in with root's VNC, and setup a new user in vnc. But this new user's VNC can still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have a graphical desktop configured, or just a console shell?  If not, then VNC won't have a desktop to show them.

Comment: I just use useradd command to add the user. Is there a way to decide whether this user can have graphical desktop?

Comment: But actually vnc somehow worked for the new user after rebooting...